# InstanceOwnerException after Windows returns from sleep

Tags: windows, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

Perhaps any of you can help me with this anoying problem. I have long running workflow, that is used by a long running application. 
I use the SqlWorkflowInstanceStore for persistence. 
I set the DefaultInstanceOwner so I can reload the workflows on another startup of the app.

```
InstanceHandle handle = workflowInstanceStore.CreateInstanceHandle();
InstanceView view = workflowInstanceStore.Execute(handle, 
                          new CreateWorkflowOwnerCommand(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
handle.Free();
workflowInstanceStore.DefaultInstanceOwner = view.InstanceOwner;
```

and I delete it at app exit :

```
 var deleteOwnerCmd = new DeleteWorkflowOwnerCommand();
 InstanceHandle handle = workflowInstanceStore.CreateInstanceHandle();
 workflowInstanceStore.Execute(handle, deleteOwnerCmd, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
 handle.Free();
```

**Everything goes well under normal app use. The problem occurs if windows gets into sleep mode. When it returns from the sleep mode, any other operation with the workflowInstanceStore throws:**

```
System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.InstanceOwnerException: The execution of an InstancePersistenceCommand was interrupted because the instance owner registration for owner ID 'GUID' has become invalid. This error indicates that the in-memory copy of all instances locked by this owner have become stale and should be discarded, along with the InstanceHandles. Typically, this error is best handled by restarting the host.
```

I took a look in the database in the LockOwnersTable and the lock expiration is set to 2000-01-01 00:00:00.000 when the system wakes up.

Any ideas to find the root cause for this behavior or workarounds are welcome. I already took the first workaround, that is disabled sleep mode...

Comment: Very interesting - if I can reproduce this I'd like to file a bug.  Do you have a simple repro I can look at?

Comment: Same problem here. Did you found any other solution?

Comment: The solution is indeed to check on system resume if the WorkflowInstanceOwner has become invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cause of this behavior, is that the workflow instance store is supposed to tell the database it is still alived at regular time interval (defined by the HostLockRenewalPeriod property). When the computer is in sleep mode it can not update the LockExpiration column of LockOwnersTable, and the workflow instance store is considered defunct.

A solution is to restart the instance store when the computer resume from sleep mode.
You can detect this by registering the Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged event.